# itemSelected not fired in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I'm trying to develop a sign-up menu for a social app, that I'm working on. I would like the sign-up menu to consist of a PageViewer, which holds five fragments. The last three fragments contains a ListView, where the user can 'check' information about them selves. The XML is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:id="@+id/layoutSignupLists">
    <TextView
        android:text="Add something here"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/signupListDescription" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/interestListView"
        android:layout_below="@id/signupListDescription"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This layout is inflated, when the last three fragments are created as is displayed correctly. I have subscribed a delegate to the itemSelected event in the ListView as seen below:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //Inflate view and find content
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.signupFragLayout4, container, false);
        interestListView = view.FindViewById <ListView>(Resource.Id.interestListView);
        var desc = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.signupListDescription);

        //Adds the description
        desc.Text = GetString(Resource.String.profile_menu_edit_interests);

        //Populate ListView
        interestListView.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Activity, 
            Resource.Layout.CheckedListViewItem, MainActivity.InfoNames[(int)InfoType.Interest]);
        interestListView.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Multiple;
        interestListView.ItemSelected +=  (object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e) => 
            {
                if(!Interests.Contains(e.Position))
                    Interests.Add(e.Position);
                else
                    Interests.Remove(e.Position);
            };

        return view;
    }
```

When putting a break-point in the delegate I find that it's never called and thus the ListView reset upon swiping right or left.

How can I make the fragment 'hold on' to the information so that it's displayed every time the fragment is shown?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but Android recommends using [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) instead of [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView).

Answer (score 0):

Place the information in the MainActivity. You can make a simple reference to it by putting this variable in your fragment class:

```
MainActivity mainActivity;
```

And in your `OnCreateView()` place this to initialize it:

```
mainActivity = (MainActivity)Activity;
```

Now if you have any public variables in the mainActivity, you can reference them in the fragment like:

```
textView.Text = mainActivity.VariableName;
```

Additionally, for putting the information back in the fragment, override the 'OnResume' method like so:

```
   public override void OnResume()
   {
       base.OnResume();
       //Code to fill in all the information in your fragment again. I.E:
       textView.Text = mainActivity.VariableName;
   }
```